# Mysql 5.5 Adds Default Value Automatically for Primary Keys

Tags: mysql, mariadb

When I run following query in **mysql 5.5**, I can see the table has a default value `''` for the primary key even though I've not specified it

```
CREATE TABLE `test1` (
  `id` VARCHAR(10),
  `data` VARCHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

When I run following query in **mysql 5.5**, I can see the table has a default value `'0'` for the primary key even though I've not specified it

```
CREATE TABLE `test2` (
  `id` int(10),
  `data` VARCHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

This doesn't happen in **mariadb 10.2**.

I used to compare database structures using the values in information_schema. But now it seems to be not possible to compare default values of 2 table columns from 5.5 and 10.2 databases. Anybody knows why this is automatically added?  And a solution for this?

Comment: What does MariaDB 10.2 do?

Answer (score 3):

According to [MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/primary-keys-with-nullable-columns/) `MariaDB` before the version `10.1.7` and `MySQL` before the version `5.7` convert such columns into a NOT NULL column with a default value of 0. But then both DBs changed their behaviour and currently the column is converted to NOT NULL, but without a default value.

Thus, you can change one of your DB version to achieve the same behaviour

Answer (score 0):

If a column definition includes no explicit DEFAULT value, MySQL determines the default values.

Answer (score 0):

Since Primary key cant be NULL & cant be duplicate, MYSQL assign default value for the first record if you don't specify a value to it at the time of record insert.
You can set this primary key as auto increment and you can also insert values if you want even after it is of type auto increment ( If you Want ).